# changes in php.ini file being ignored

Tags: php, apache2

I am having a hard time with this. I am trying to increase

```
post_max_size = 90M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

but my info.php is still showing default values 20M

I am editing 100% correct file which is being loaded by apache2, I took path directly from phpinfo page. I do have .htaccess file but nothing in there should override php settings.

I have tried many solutions available but no success. One of those were: stackoverflow.com/questions/14327409/changes-to-upload-max-filesize-in-ubuntu-php-ini-will-not-take-effect

First answer seem to work for people but it would not work for me. I created 30-user.ini file with these values but no luck. (I checked correct path for config directory I double checked)

Another solution for some was to simply restart server. I don't see how this would work and haven't tried it because I don't want downtimes.

I am using ubuntu 16 server and php7.0 I restarted apache2 but not sure how to restart php, if thats required too.

Maybe putting those values into .htaccess file would help? but not sure how syntax should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I found out adding those values inside .htaccess file works. It is not desired solution though, I really want to know why it didn't work. If anybody has got any clue, I will be glad.